# can't select a data in chosen using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen select option.In my situation, i have to select an option by jquery.

The select option has options like {monkey,Lion,Tiger,2dog,Other...etc}.I am selecting a word by jquery as follows.

```
jQuery("#aselect").val('Lion');          
jQuery("#aselect").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

It works well for the string 'Lion' but i can't select the word with 'tiger'.Because T is in Uppercase in select list.But My datas taken from the database..

So how i can achieve this?or I have to follow some rule like always keep small or Caps same for all words..

Please help me..

Edited:
Now i tried this,

```
jQuery("#aselect").val('tiger').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

But,To Select 'Tiger',instead this code add a new option 'tiger'?

now my list has new item {...Tiger,..,tiger,..etc}
So I need to select a matched value...

Comment: Can you fiddle your code please .Thanks

Comment: 1st : you can do jQuery("#aselect").val('Lion').trigger("chosen:updated");
2nd : you need jQuery("#aselect").val('Lion');
3rd : check
is there any dropdown with that id and option value="Lion"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.toLowerCase()` to convert the values in lower case and then check whether they are equal or not.

```
var t = 'Tiger'; //store value inside a variable

$('#aselect option').each(function() {    //loop through select options
  if( this.value.toLowerCase() === t.toLowerCase() ) { 
    $(this).attr('selected','selected'); // or $(this).prop('selected',true);
    $("#aselect").trigger("chosen:updated");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Kartikeya.But In my scenario the value which i want to select can be anything can be like (1one,two,Three,fo4,five.).So in this this will not work ..my assumption is how to use search option with jquery...

Comment: I tried, but it's not working for the words which not correctly(list M: myvalue m) match the word in the list..

Comment: I am trying to select the word 'manik' but the select option has 'Manik'.so the code not works for this scenario..

Comment: @Manik...that is what i m showing in my answer just convert the values in lowercase and check if it is equal or not.

Comment: You are right @Kartikeya..the values are compared with their lowercases..but after comparing the values,if matched the matched value in select options have to be selected right?.But it is not selected..(i tried ur's,sorry its not works).

Comment: Thank you So much @Kartikeya This is what i expect(how to select the list from the searchoptions)..I solved it with updated code..Thank you again..

Comment: a small addition to your code with single line.    jQuery("#aselect").trigger("chosen:updated"); inside the comparing condtion.. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Finally with the help of @Kartikeya I solved it..

```
temp = 'tiger';
jQuery("aselect option").each(function() {   
    if(this.value.toLowerCase() === temp.toLowerCase() ) { 
        jQuery(this).attr("selected","selected");
        jQuery("#aselect").trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
});
```

It finally select the 
Tiger in the select options...

Comment: This is not worked for special characters(1tig,'ei,"hu,...etc).